# How to assign API fetch random colors on elements with same ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, api

I am creating a bootstrap card on click using jQuery on-click and card has an ID which I use to add background-color through an API fetched random color. When I assign background-color to the ID, one color is applied to all the cards which I create on-click but I want to set different color to the card I create on-click.

Note: I am new to API and jQuery.

Correct me if I am missing a very small and easy step.

```js
// Set API fetched colors and input texts
function btnClick(){
    $(".flex-item:last").append("<div class=card id=card><div class=card-body><h5 class=card-title id=card_title></h5></div></div>");

    fetch('http://api.creativehandles.com/getRandomColor') 
    .then(function(response) {
        
        response.json().then(function(data){
            var color = data["color"];
            var card = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
            var i;
            for (i=0; i<card.length; i++ ) {
                if (color == "") {
                    document.getElementById("card").style.backgroundColor = "#6D4298";
                    document.getElementById("card").style.color = "#FFFFFF";
                } else {
                    card[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
                    document.getElementById("btn_submit").style.borderColor = color;
                    document.getElementById("textField").style.borderColor = color;
                }   
            }
            
                    
        })

    })
};
```

```html
<!-- Card -->
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="input-container">
      <input type="text" class="title-input" id="textField" name="textField" placeholder="Type card title" required></input>
      <button type="submit" id="btn_submit" onclick="btnClick()" value="Create card">Create card</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Set API fetched colors and input texts
function btnClick() {
  var parentForLastAdded = $(".flex-item:last").append("<div class=card id=card><div class=card-body><h5 class=card-title id=card_title></h5></div></div>");
  var lastAdded = parentForLastAdded.find(".card:last-child");

  fetch('http://api.creativehandles.com/getRandomColor')
    .then(function(response) {

      response.json().then(function(data) {
        var color = data["color"];

        if (color == "") {
          lastAdded.css("background-color", "#6D4298");
          lastAdded.css("color", "#FFFFFF");
        } else {
          lastAdded.css("background-color", color);
          document.getElementById("btn_submit").style.borderColor = color;
          document.getElementById("textField").style.borderColor = color;
        }



      })

    })
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Card -->
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="input-container">
      <input type="text" class="title-input" id="textField" name="textField" placeholder="Type card title" required></input>
      <button type="submit" id="btn_submit" onclick="btnClick()" value="Create card">Create card</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You are using `document.getElementsByClassName("card")` to get all elements with `card` class but after all you are using `document.getElementById`.

Id should be unique in html documents and you are using same Id for all. Using `document.getElementById` will just return the first element with that Id.

If you want to just affect the last added element you should query for that element with specific selector for `:last-child` in parent element.

As you are using the `append` function of jQuery and this function returns the parent where the element was added you can get the `.card:last-child` element on it into a variable and use it. Take in account last added element returned by jQuery append will be an jQuery object and not a HTML Dom element so you can use the `css` method.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id

  > If the id value is not the empty string, it must be unique in a
  >   document.
- https://api.jquery.com/append/
- https://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value

Comment: I want to have the same ID and background-color to affect only the last added element. I tried what you said and it makes sense to me now. Thanks for the answering and teaching me.